# VB.net SendMessage with CB_ADDSTRING '0' not valid for 'index'

Tags: windows, vb.net, api, indexing

I'm trying to fasten up the loading of one form, which populates several combobox with a big amount of data. I did my best stopping the UI while loading ecc shredding the loading time from 20s to 13s, but still the only bottleneck remaining is loading data into ComboBox which takes about 3-4s each. I did research on the internet and found that using Windows API you can fasten it up a lot more. So I did the code:

```
Private Const CB_ERR As Integer = -1
Private Const CB_ADDSTRING As Integer = &H143
Private Const CB_SETITEMDATA As Integer = &H151

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Private Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, lParam As String) As Integer
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Private Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, lParam As Object) As Integer
End Function

Public Sub AddItem(cmb As ComboBox, Item As Object)
    Dim l As Integer

    l = SendMessage(cmb.Handle, CB_ADDSTRING, 0&, Item.ToString())
    SendMessage(cmb.Handle, CB_SETITEMDATA, l, Item)

End Sub
```

But on CB_ADDSTRING the program crashes with this error (that can be catched):

> InvalidArgument=Value of '0' not valid for 'index'. Parameter Name: index

Comment: This is not going well.  Quite unlikely this exception is raised in this code, look at the exception's stack trace to find the bad code back.  Possibly a bad SubString() call on an empty string.  Notable is that the SendMessage declarations are not correct, that can cause more misery in the future, the wParam argument and the return value are IntPtr.  If you want to make this kind of code faster then it is important that you use the constructor instead of the Load event.  And give the user a break, nobody likes having to dig through thousands of items.

Answer (score -1):

Since I'm using Krypton Controls, I had to shuffle trough Parents until I found KryptonComboBox, and then pass it's Handle value.